# Literature & Multi-Precision packages for Factorising Large Integers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization

I will be doing a project on factorising large integers and the standard book people keep recommending to me is Henri Cohen's book "A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory". It is in fact quite a good read, but it is also fairly old.

So my questions are:

1. Are there any *recent* publications that deal with factorising large integers, specifically the quadratic sieve and/or number field sieve? Introductory as well as advanced publications would be great.
2. Since I also want to implement a few algorithms I need a good/fast/reliable multi-precision package (preferably for C/C++) which is suited for calculation with large integers.

I would appreciate any kind of suggestions.

Comment: Cohen's book was published in 2000 -- was that really that long ago? I was going to cite Murphy's "Polynomial Selection for the Number Field Sieve Integer Factroisation Algorithm" which, along with Briggs' "An Introduction to the General Number Field Sieve", is the standard practical NFS reference as far as I know, but those are both older than the book.

Comment: I thought Cohen's book was first published in 1993? I may be wrong, of course. edit: But thanks for your references, I shall have a look at those.

Comment: Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective [Paperback]
Richard Crandall (Author), Carl B. Pomerance (Author), libtommath or see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic. Cohen is an awesome book, but check out the one I refer too also.

Answer (score 1):

Hig-precision packages are [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org), [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/Download.html). There sure are others.